# Firebase Google authentication error in ionic3

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

auth.ts

```
signInWithGoogle(): firebase.Promise<any> {
return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());}
```

login.ts

```
loginGoogle() {
this.authData.signInWithGoogle().then(() => {
  this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
}, error => {
  this.presentToast("Invalid user details");
});}
```

Open the google account selector and app working smoothly in mobile when select and account to authenticate from the list it display a message

**mobile app identifier is not registered for the current project**

Message showing:

[image: Message showing is...]

Please help me to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Are you following these steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

Comment: Yes I following this steps but bit confused about where to add following code section in ionic 3 project.@bojeil `<universal-links>
    <host name="DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN" scheme="https" />
    <host name="AUTH_DOMAIN" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
    </host>
</universal-links>`

Comment: `<universal-links>
    <host name="DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN" scheme="https" />
    <host name="AUTH_DOMAIN" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
    </host>
</universal-links>`

Comment: I found that great. Thank you!

Comment: sorry I do not understand, what change in the universal-link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by updating my widget id (in the config.xml file, to match the app id in the firebase console.

Comment: what is ID the app in firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You should add App **Android** to your Firebase Account with same ID of your config in widget id

[image]

[image]